# VSCode snippet: How to set file type also?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I created a snippet for quick starting a pure react component like this:

```
     {"new React Pure": {
        "prefix": "reactpure",
        "body": [
            "import React from 'react';",
            "import PropTypes from 'prop-types';",
            "import './${1:ComponentName}.module.css';",
            "const ${1:ComponentName} = ({ ${2:propValue=[] } }) => (",
            "<${3:rootelement}>${4:content}</${3:rootelement}>",
            ")",
            "${1:ComponentName}.propTypes = {",
            "${5:propValue}: PropTypes.string",
            "};",
            "export default ${1:ComponentName};",
            "$0"
        ],
        "description": "Create a react pure component"
    }
```

This works fine. But my problem is, I need to set/change the file type from `plaintext` to `javascriptreact` everytime I create a new component, to see the color theme and other autocompletes to work. Is there a way to set the filetype of any empty file if I used some particular snippet?

I understand snippets normally used to do small tasks where the file is already created. But I am using this snippets extensively now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: With vscode v1.59 there is this preview feature:

`"workbench.editor.untitled.experimentalLanguageDetection": true`

If I copy/paste your code it detects it as `typescript` and not `javascriptreact` so that doesn't help.  Nor does it do any detection when the text is input via a snippet.  It is a preview feature so you could make a new issue on this.

---

One thing you could do is set the default language mode for new files:

```
"files.defaultLanguage": "javascriptreact",
```

Otherwise there is a hacky way which works well.  You will need a macro extension like [multiCommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

Here is your macro which goes in your settings:

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.languageMode",
  "sequence": [

    // make a new untitled file - you may or may not want this
    "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
    {
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "name": "new React Pure"
      }
    },
    "workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode",

    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",

    "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem"
  ]
},
```

There are 27 `quickOpenNavigateNext`'s based on how far down in the language mode quick pick panel I have to scroll to get to `javascriptreact`. Your mileage may vary if you have added language modes to the defaults.

First that macro inserts the `"new React Pure"` snippet from your question.

Then bind that macro to some keychord and trigger that.  It will create a new untitled file, set its language mode to `"javascriptreact"` and enter your react snippet ready for editing.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
    "command": "multiCommand.languageMode",
},
```

It is a bit of a pain but I don't know a way to programmatically provide input to the quickpick panel.

But I suppose an extension is really the way to go.  There is this api that would be useful:

```
openTextDocument({ language: 'javascriptreact' })
```

but that command I do not believe can be invoked without using an extension.

Comment: okay. I went with the default language settings. Anyway, after I save the file to a different filetype, it automatically changes it. So it will work for me.